# Is there a way I can get my Google Font code to work for my HTML code?

Tags: html

I'm trying to add a font to my HTML code, using the website, [Neocities](https://www.neocities.org), and when I add the font, I get an error that says `Name entity expected. Got none.` I've tried searching p how I can fix this error, but I've had no luck. Here is the code that Google Fonts gave me to use: `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">`
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre] so we can exaclty reproduce the issue.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is an '&' symbol inside a link or src. HTML don't read entities like ampersand symbols. You should use %26 as an ampersand instead.

Comment: Ok, I removed the '&' symbol, but now when I save my code and click view, my website shows everything in the default font, and not what I put. I did follow what Google said and pt the code it game me in my <head> tag.